# Best Way to Extract Values from a String that can take many forms and is Loaded from a .properties file in Java

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a **ws.properties** file in which there's a property called **success.code** that gives me the option the choose which HTTP Status success codes (2xx), aside from the default 200, I want the server to treat as "Success" as well.

The idea is like this:

1. If I enter the value like this:

> success.code=201,202, 203 (values separated by a comma)

The part of the code responsible for extracting this value should immediately understand that these are three separate codes, extract each one of them and store them in a list or set or....

This is actually pretty easy:

```
private Set<String[]> getSuccessCodes(HashMap<String, String> codes){
    Set<String[]> successCodes = new HashSet<>();
    String value;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : codes.entrySet()) {
        value = entry.getValue();
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(value))
            successCodes.add(value.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    }
    return successCodes;
}
```

2. Here's where it gets a little complicated:

I would also like to add these options as well:

> success.code=[202, 220] (two values written between hooks and separated by a comma)

- [202, 220]: when the value is written like this, I want the above method to understand that I want all the values between 202 and 220 to be extracted, stored and returned like I did with the first case.

> success.code=2**

- This means that all the codes starting with 2 (so from 201 until 299) should be stored in a set or a list and returned back to me in that methods

> success.code=[200, 205], 22*

- this means that I want the code to return to me all the codes between 200 and 205 (so 200, 201, 202,.., 2005) plus the code that goes from 220 to 220.

So depending on the value that I enter for the success code, the program should be able to understand what to do and what to return from it.

Is this achievable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might need to separate each use case with regex and then apply the logic for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind adding three more methods, here is one approach:

- Split your vlaues using `"\\s*,\\s*(?![^\\[]*\\])"` to split at each comma unless in brackets
- Itereate/ stream over the resulting array and map each element checking if it contains `[` or `*`
- If it contains `[` generate an `IntStream.rangeClosed(x,y)` using the values in `[x,y]` and map them to their string values
- If it contains `*` generate an `IntStream.rangeClosed(x00,x99)` by replacing `*` with `0` and `9` and map them to their string values

Something like:

```
private static Set<String[]> getSuccessCodes(HashMap<String, String> codes){
    Set<String[]> successCodes = new HashSet<>();
    String value;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : codes.entrySet()) {
        value = entry.getValue();
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(value))
            successCodes.add(parse(value));
    }
    return successCodes;
}
public static String[] parse(String val) {
    String[] parts = val.split("\\s*,\\s*(?![^\\[]*\\])");
    return Arrays.stream(parts)
          .map(e -> e.contains("[")? getRangeCodes(e): e.contains("*")? getWildCCodes(e): e)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(",")).split("\\s*,\\s*");
}
private static String getRangeCodes(String e) {
    e = e.substring(1, e.length()-1);
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(Integer.parseInt(e.split("\\s*,\\s*")[0]), Integer.parseInt(e.split("\\s*,\\s*")[1]))
            .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}

private static String getWildCCodes(String e) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(Integer.parseInt(e.replace('*', '0')), Integer.parseInt(e.replace('*', '9')))
            .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Tested with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    HashMap<String, String> codes = new HashMap<>();
    codes.put("foo", "201, 202, 203");
    codes.put("bar", "[202, 220]");
    codes.put("baz", "2**");
    codes.put("doo", "[200, 205], 22*");
    codes.put("woo", "200, 201, 202, 203,[209, 214], 29*");

    Set<String[]> set = getSuccessCodes(codes);
    set.forEach(s -> {System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));});
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Just brilliant. If I could thumb up your comment a thousand times I would. 

Not only is it elegant, but it also works with all the possibility that I have tested with so far. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of requiring your program to accept some elaborate grammar that you defined, why not let the framework do what it does naturally?

`success.codes = 201,202,203`

`success.code.min = 202
success.code.max = 220`

`success.code.prefix = 22`

Then combine these properties in your code as you see fit. This is the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the answer is definitely **yes it is achievable**. The solution would be that you will have to write your own parser or mini-interpreter that would take your String and first "compile" it - i.e. check that it is a valid input (say that number of "[" is equal to number of "]" and that at no point while parsing the number of "]" is not greater then number of "]" i.e. String "[...]][" should be declared invalid). And then it would interpret it. The more flexible you want your language to be the more complex your interpreter would be. Most likely Regular expressions won't be enough. But in general you will need to write a method with signature like this:

```
Set<Integer> parseHttpCodesParam(String input);
```

Your implementation will have several rules

1. How to treat comma-separated integer values
2. How to treat two comma-separated numbers within []
3. How to treat special chars like *

etc